# Enabling code completion for bootstrap.js in PhpStorm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, phpstorm

For some reason I get no code completion for the bootstrap.js.
I added the non minified version from https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js as well as adding the library manually in the javascript library settings.

Same thing happened for me with knockout until I found out I have to use the knockout-debug version since this is the non minified version.

But for bootstrap it isn't working.

Comment: Please show screenshot of that library.

Comment: I just the library from the link. The manually added library is the one from the bootstrap dist package. -
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6066/SeCcK0.png - 
http://imageshack.com/a/img540/8669/3hGHyt.png

Comment: Suggestions: 1) add both minified and not versions of bootstrap in the same library (Release & Debug accordingly) and not in 2 separate;  2) Try "Project" Visibility instead of "Global"; 3) Have both files (minified and not) inside the project. At very least that is what works for me (I'm on Windows)

Comment: I tried exactly that but still no completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had no completion for 'typeahead'. Didn't bother to try other functions from bootstrap as I wasn't expecting to get completion for them ever.
Found out they dropped exactly that in favor of twitter's [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/).

But thanks for the help [@LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone).